# JOptionPane YES NO OPTION

Tags: java, swing, applet, awt, joptionpane

I got an JOptionPane and yes and no buttons. But, whichever button  you click it still exists. HELP! Heres the code:

```
int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;
            JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Are you sure?","WARNING", dialogButton);
            if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
                  remove(dialogButton);
                }
              }
```

Comment: for better help sooner post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/), short, runnable, compilable, otherwise answers to your very vague question couldn't ...., be sure that before to read [Oracle tutorial How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html)

Answer (score 23, accepted):

You should actually take the result from the option pane:

```
dialogButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Are you sure?","WARNING", dialogButton);
```

Otherwise, it remains set to `JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION`.

Cleaner would be:

```
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null, "Are you sure?", "WARNING",
        JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    // yes option
} else {
    // no option
}
```

Although, I'm not sure what this line is expected to do in the posted code: `remove(dialogButton);`.

For more details and examples check out [How to Make Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/dialog.html) tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

```
int dialogButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Are you sure?","WARNING",JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);

if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
System.exit(0);}else {remove(dialogButton);}
```

this is the correct!

Comment: but remove(dialogButton); is wrong

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! You can [edit] your posts and delete your comments. Please go ahead and add your comment to your answer. While you're at it, you should describe why you think this is such a good solution and why `remove()` is wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Change the code to

`int dialogButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Are you sure?","WARNING", dialogButton);`

Answer (score 0):

```
if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) { // <<< start
    System.exit(0);
        if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.NO_OPTION) {
            remove(dialogButton);
        }
}// <<< stop
```

The result is caused by the fact that the outer `if` encloses the other `if` statement, make sure you don't next the `if` statement, it should be as follows : -

```
if(dialogButton == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    System.exit(0);
}else {
    remove(dialogButton);
}
```

Another thing is this line `int dialogButton = JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION;`, change it to

```
int dialogButton = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog (null, "Are you sure?","WARNING", dialogButton);
```

Comment: thats not the problem. and else, and else if doesnt work for me

Answer (score 0):

If you want the JOptionPane to be gone then you can:

```
optionPane.setVisible(false);
```

If you don't then look at a different answer.

Answer (score -1):

```
if (JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this, "sfd", "sd", JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION) == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
    jProgressBar1.setValue(jProgressBar1.getValue() + 10);
    jProgressBar1.setComponentOrientation(ComponentOrientation.RIGHT_TO_LEFT);
}
else {
    System.exit(0);
}
```